# Fat-free framework: how to display a calendar using the Matrix class?

Tags: fat-free-framework

```php
$matrix = \Matrix::instance();
$cal = $matrix->calendar('2014-06', 1);
```

I can not work out how to use data in `$cal` & get it to display in view

Answer (score 0):

The `calendar()` method returns an array of weeks.

Here's a basic example:

**index.php**

```php
$f3=require('lib/base.php');

$f3->route('GET /cal/@year/@month',function($f3,$params){
  $f3->cal=Matrix::instance()->calendar($params['year'].'-'.$params['month'],1);
  $f3->title=date('F Y',mktime(0,0,0,$params['month'],1,$params['year']));
  echo Template::instance()->render('cal.html');

});

$f3->run();
```

**cal.html**

```
<h1>{{ @title }}</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Mo</th>
            <th>Tu</th>
            <th>We</th>
            <th>Th</th>
            <th>Fr</th>
            <th>Sa</th>
            <th>Su</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <repeat group="@cal" value="@week">
            <tr>
                <loop from="$d=0" to="$d<7" step="$d++">
                    <td>{{ @@week[ @d ] }}</td>
                </loop>
            </tr>
        </repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now `GET /cal/2014/06` should return something like:

[image: Calendar June 2014]

Comment: thank you very much xfra35; i was looking at displaying calendars from data in MySQL for a simple booking system  to add to web using f3 . I have gone for a a varchar field so one record holds data like: 24    25     26    27     28   29    30 (week 35 august ) 31     .     .     .     .     .     . (week 36 august ) and use <pre></pre> to keep data to display as required